# I have a loop and want to add the class to the last 4 elements with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am wanting to select the last 4 elements using nth-child. Is there a way of doing this?

```
function(data){
    var output;
    var html = "";
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
    videoTitle = item.snippet.title;
    videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
    console.log(i);
    html += "<div id=\"video\" class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 link-js\">\n" +
                  "         <iframe width=\"100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoId+"\"></iframe>\n" +
        "    </div>"
});
$('#youtube-v3').append(html);
}
```

Comment: My loop consists of 8 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to remove the `id` attribute from the HTML you create as you're creating duplicates which is invalid. `id` have to be unique within the DOM. Change it to a class.

Then you can what you require outside of your loop using `slice()`. It's also possible to simplify the code and make it more performant by using `map()` to create the HTML from the `data.items` array and calling `append()` only once.

```js
function(data) {
  var html = data.items.map(item => `<div class="video col-xs-12 col-sm-6 link-js"><iframe width="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/${item.snippet.resourceId.videoId}"></iframe></div>`);
  $('#youtube-v3').append(html);

  var $lastVideos = $('.video').slice(-4);
  // do something with the last 4 videos here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using a loop,`compare the index in the loop with the length of the array` and you can check if `index >= 4`. 
Using this, add your desired class only when **index >= 4**, which will be true only for elements after 4th one (i.e. 5th,6th,7th,8th element)

PS: Remove the same `id` on HTML tags.